# How to find a unassigned drive letter on windows with python

Tags: python, windows, windows-shell, network-drive

I needed to find a free drive letter on windows from a python script. Free stands for not assigned to any physically or remote device.

I did some research and found a solution here on stackoverflow (cant remember the exact link):

```
# for python 2.7
import string
import win32api

def getfreedriveletter():
    """ Find first free drive letter """
    assigneddrives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]
    assigneddrives = [item.rstrip(':\\').lower() for item in assigneddrives]
    for driveletter in list(string.ascii_lowercase[2:]):
        if not driveletter in assigneddrives:
            return driveletter.upper() + ':'
```

This works fine for all physically drives and connected network drives. But not for currently disconnected drives.
How can I get all used drive letter, also the temporary not used ones?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for opinions on how to improve working code. That's a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What is the correct way to share a solution? When I was looking for this question, a week before, I would be happy if someone elses had shared his solution before.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Why don't you use WMIC command for this? `wmic logicaldisk get Caption`, this gives you all used drive letters.

Comment: @Dominique But this will not show you currently not connected drives.
Result from your command:
`Caption
C:
D:
E:`

 Result from net use:
`New connections will not be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  B:        \\SOMESERVER\SOMEFOLDER$
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  F:        \\SOMESERVER\ABC$         Microsoft Windows Network`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a child process is relatively expensive, and parsing free-form text output isn't the most reliable technique. You can instead use PyWin32 to call the same API functions that `net use` calls.

```
import string
import win32api
import win32wnet
import win32netcon

def get_free_drive():
    drives = set(string.ascii_uppercase[2:])
    for d in win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split(':\\\x00'):
        drives.discard(d)
    # Discard persistent network drives, even if not connected.
    henum = win32wnet.WNetOpenEnum(win32netcon.RESOURCE_REMEMBERED, 
        win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 0, None)
    while True:
        result = win32wnet.WNetEnumResource(henum)
        if not result:
            break
        for r in result:
            if len(r.lpLocalName) == 2 and r.lpLocalName[1] == ':':
                drives.discard(r.lpLocalName[0])
    if drives:
        return sorted(drives)[-1] + ':'
```

Note that this function returns the last available drive letter. It's a common practice to assign mapped and substitute drives (e.g. from net.exe and subst.exe) from the end of the list and local system drives from the beginning.

Comment: I was not aware of win32wnet and win32netcon and its functions thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As i will pass the found letter to an external script which will run the Winshell cmd 'subst /d *letter*'. I must not pass a currently not mounted drive, as it will remove the network-drive mapping.

The only way I found, was the result of the winshellcmd 'net use' to find unavailable drives.

Here is my solution, if you have a better way, please share it with me:

```
# for python 2.7
import string
import win32api
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def _getnetdrives():
""" As _getfreedriveletter can not find unconnected network drives
    get these drives with shell cmd 'net use' """
    callstr = 'net use'
    phandle = Popen(callstr, stdout=PIPE)
    presult = phandle.communicate()
    stdout = presult[0]
    # _stderr = presult[1]
    networkdriveletters = []
    for line in stdout.split('\n'):
        if ':        ' in line:
             networkdriveletters.append(line.split()[1] + '\\')
    return networkdriveletters

def getfreedriveletter():
    """ Find first free drive letter """
    assigneddrives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings().split('\000')[:-1]
    assigneddrives = assigneddrives + _getnetdrives()
    assigneddrives = [item.rstrip(':\\').lower() for item in assigneddrives]
    for driveletter in list(string.ascii_lowercase[2:]): #array starts from 'c' as i dont want a and b drive
        if not driveletter in assigneddrives:
        return driveletter.upper() + ':'
```